# Why is vector v used instead of its perpendicular component v⊥ in this cross product calculation?

Tags: vectors, rotations

[image: Vector Rotation]

Sorry if this is a dumb question. I'm learning about 3D computer graphics and how to rotate a vector $\mathbf v$ around an arbitrary unit vector axis $\mathbf n$ by angle $\theta$. What I don't get is why $\mathbf v$ is used in the cross product calculation $\mathbf n×\mathbf v$ instead of the perpendicular component $\mathbf v_⊥$, since we're trying to find a vector that's orthogonal to both $\mathbf v_⊥$ and $n$.

Comment: I haven't looked at your picture, but I suspect that $n\times v=n\times v_\perp$. So, why bother calculating $v_\perp$?

Comment: Yeah you're right. I'm new to the cross product so it wasn't intuitively obvious why that was the case at first. Thanks!